# Text Pattern Recognition - Model building using R

Tags: r, text, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

I have a training dataset which has two columns which has around 70 values.

1. “PNRNo” whose values like UT767G, CADA, 4I9I59, 4BH5TW…(typical PNR number patterns)
2. I have created one more factor variable mentioning (IsPNR) – so all the values are 1 (true)

My first objective is to create a model on this training set which would recognize the text pattern.

Second objective: The  model would then be used to predict IsPNR with new set of test values like “Anshuk”, “4EL58S”…as 0 and 1…

Which model would be best for recognizing such kind of pattern and having decent accuracy? I tried naiveBayes, but I don’t think it is all doing a good job. Its predicting all the test values as true. I suppose bayes is not meant for this.

Comment: I think you'd get much better answers on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @nico posted the same, thanks.